# add price to barcode generated serial

Tags: c#, winforms, barcode

I have created a code to print barcode on a barcode printer, but now trying to add to the printing the price for the product which is in a textbox

here is my code

```
        private void frmAddProduct_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string barcode = txtCode.Text;

            Bitmap bitm = new Bitmap(barcode.Length * 40, 110);

            using (Graphics graphic = Graphics.FromImage(bitm))
            {


                Font newfont = new Font("IDAutomationHC39M", 14);
                PointF point = new PointF(2f, 2f);
                SolidBrush black = new SolidBrush(Color.Black);
                SolidBrush white = new SolidBrush(Color.White);
                graphic.FillRectangle(white, 0, 0, bitm.Width, bitm.Height);
                graphic.DrawString("*" + barcode + "*", newfont, black, point);


            }

            using (MemoryStream Mmst = new MemoryStream())
            {


                bitm.Save("ms", ImageFormat.Jpeg);
                pictureBox1.Image = bitm;
                pictureBox1.Width = bitm.Width;
                pictureBox1.Height = bitm.Height;


            }  
        }

        private void btnCodePrint_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            short numCopies = 0;
            numCopies = Convert.ToInt16(txtCodeNo.Text);

            PrintDialog pd = new PrintDialog();

            pd.PrinterSettings = new PrinterSettings();

            if (DialogResult.OK == pd.ShowDialog(this))
            {

                PrintDocument pdoc = new PrintDocument();

                pdoc.PrintPage += new PrintPageEventHandler(pqr);
                pdoc.PrinterSettings.Copies = numCopies;

                pdoc.Print();

            }
        }
```

[image]

that's the issue I'm currently having, I want to add the price from the textbox into the barcode above or under the barcode in the image attached but I can't seem to find a way to make this work, everything I try makes the barcode not work

EDIT

I tried this but showed the price above the barcode

```
string barcode = txtCode.Text;
            string price = txtPprice.Text;
            Bitmap bitm = new Bitmap(barcode.Length * 40, 110);

            using (Graphics graphic = Graphics.FromImage(bitm))
            {


                Font newfont = new Font("IDAutomationHC39M", 14);
                Font newfont2 = new Font("Arial", 14);
                PointF point = new PointF(2f, 2f);
                SolidBrush black = new SolidBrush(Color.Black);
                SolidBrush white = new SolidBrush(Color.White);
                graphic.FillRectangle(white, 0, 0, bitm.Width, bitm.Height);
                graphic.DrawString("*" + price + "*", newfont2, black, point);
                graphic.DrawString("*" + barcode + "*", newfont, black, point);
```

Comment: `everything I try makes the barcode not work` explain this better, i mean how does it make the barcode not work, also can you show an example of what you did to make it not work

Comment: edited the question with that part

Comment: Could you edit the first sentence? It is grammatically not clear to me "*but now trying to add to the printing the price for the product which is in a textbox*".

Comment: Mohammed, it is simple.. I show the barcode as an image for printing, I want the product price to appear above it.
my last try made the price appear but more like in the background of the barcode image, I want to make it appear above it

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is your problem, `point` is actually the point where you are drawing the bar-code, and you are using it to draw your price as well. You will need to make a new point, i.e a different coordinate

```
...
// a new point for your price
PointF pointPrice = new PointF(20f, 20f);
// Draw your price
graphic.DrawString("*" + price + "*", newfont2, black, pointPrice);
// Draw your barcode
graphic.DrawString("*" + barcode + "*", newfont, black, point);
```

Just play around with the values for `pointPrice` to figure out the placement position you want

Good luck

Comment: Don't play around with values for PointPrice, calculate it from the size of the string it generates.